# Angular - NgxTranslate - Missing Translation Handler on condition

Tags: angular, translation, ngx-translate

I have created a missing translation handler that looks up the translation in an external api, if it cannot find it then returns the original key.

```
export class MyMissingTranslationHandler implements MissingTranslationHandler {
        constructor(public injector: Injector) {}
    
        handle(params: MissingTranslationHandlerParams): string {
            const result = ApiCallToFindTheKey(params.key)
            return result ? result : params.key;
        }
    }
```

I also have some json translations files (for static app translations) that are being requested also via an api call.

```
export class MultiTranslateHttpLoader implements TranslateLoader {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    public getTranslation(lang: string): Observable<any> {
        const resources: string[] = [
            '_global.json',
            ...
        ];

        const requests = resources.map(resource => {
            const path = 'i18n/' + lang + '/' + resource;
            return this.http.get(path).pipe(
                catchError(res => {
                    console.error(res.message);
                    return of({});
                })
            );
        });
        return forkJoin(requests).pipe(map(response => merge.all(response)));
    }
}
```

The *translate pipe* is configured to use these json files and **if it cannot find the translations it falls into my missing translation handler**.

```
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient): TranslateLoader {
        return new MultiTranslateHttpLoader(http);
    }

    @NgModule({
        imports: [
            TranslateModule.forRoot({
                defaultLanguage: 'fr',
                loader: {
                    provide: TranslateLoader,
                    useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
                    deps: [HttpClient]
                },
                missingTranslationHandler: {
                    provide: MissingTranslationHandler,
                    useClass: MyMissingTranslationHandler
                }
            }),
            ...
        ]
```

Sometimes, the *json* files take a little bit too long and the *| translate pipe* thinks that translation does not exists and goes look in the missing translation handler instead of waiting for *json* file to be loaded.

So the result of the translation is what the missing translation handler returns instead of the real translation. **How can I do to make translate pipe wait for the json files to be loaded and then translate?** I thought about using some kind of *flag* but I don't know if there is a more elegant solution.

Comment: You can add a factory to load the JSONs and use APP_INITIALISER token in your app.module. This will make sure that your JSONs load before app initialises itself.

Comment: Just a guess: maybe async pipe?

Comment: That's a good idea @KanishkAnand I will try that out and I will share the results. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @KanishkAnand I use the APP_INITIALIZER.

```
/**
 * Application won't load until the translations have been downloaded
 */
export function initializeTranslations(translationLoadedService: TranslationLoadedService): () => Promise<void> {
    return async (): Promise<void> => {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            translationLoadedService.loaded$().subscribe(() => resolve());
        });
    };
}

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
            defaultLanguage: 'fr',
            loader: {
                provide: TranslateLoader,
                useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
                deps: [HttpClient, TranslationLoadedService]
            },
            missingTranslationHandler: {
                provide: MissingTranslationHandler,
                useClass: MyMissingTranslationHandler
            }
        }),
        ...
    ],
    exports: [TranslateModule],
    providers: [
        ...,
        { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: initializeTranslations, deps: [TranslationLoadedService], multi: true }
    ],
    entryComponents: ... ,
    declarations: ...
})
```

I created an intermediate service that will resolve the promise after loading all the translations.

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TranslationLoadedService {
    private translationLoaded: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();

    loaded$(): Subject<void> {
        return this.translationLoaded;
    }
}
```

So that once I get all translations downloaded I notify the subscribers.

```
export class MultiTranslateHttpLoader implements TranslateLoader {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient, private translationLoaded: TranslationLoadedService) {}

    public getTranslation(lang: string): Observable<any> {
        const resources: string[] = [
            '_global.json',
            ...
        ];

        const requests = resources.map(resource => {
            const path = 'i18n/' + lang + '/' + resource;
            return this.http.get(path).pipe(
                catchError(res => {
                    console.error('Something went wrong for the following translation file:', path);
                    console.error(res.message);
                    return of({});
                })
            );
        });
        return forkJoin(requests).pipe(
            map(response => {
                **this.translationLoaded.loaded$().next();**
                return merge.all(response);
            })
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a great implementation!